# Nginx reverse proxy https -> http

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm attempting to reverse proxy from one domain to another, across the internet.

Let's say I have https://www.primarydomain.com.

I'm attempting reverse proxy https://www.primarydomain.com/blog to a wordpress install over at http://secondarydomain.com

Here's what I have so far;

```
location /blog/ {
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host secondarydomain.com:80;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://ip-address-of-secondary-domain/;
}
```

Which results in a

```
*9503 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream
```

Worth noting that using the above config, I'm able to get this working if primarydomain.com is running on HTTP. But I can't seem to proxy the SSL version, being https://www.primarydomain.com/blog, to the HTTP webserver which is serving secondarydomain.com requests.

I'm also not doing a redirect. When I visit https://www.primarydomain.com/blog - I expect the browser URL to not change, but the wordpress install at http://secondarydomain.com to appear.

Comment: When you do a proxy I wonder if it sends a request for domain A to domain B, and that domain B doesn't know about Domain A so doesn't reply. Probably not, it would reply 404 not found. It's more likely to be firewall or a typo I think.

Comment: The "proxy_set_header Host secondarydomain.com:80;" line should be letting host B know about a domain that it recognizes.